# Windows 8.1 Durable In-app purchases

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, in-app-billing

I'm testing in-app purchases and have trouble with durable products. I can't buy any durable product more then once per game session. I'm receiving ProductPurchaseStatus.AlreadyPurchased after first buy. But if I restart app - I can purchase durable product once again. I checked my WindowsStoreProxy.xml it's same to microsoft's example. How can I puchase multiple times one durable product with simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [Consumable IAPs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn532255(v=win.10).aspx) not *Durable*. *Durable* last for a specified amount of time, when *Consumable* can be bought multiple times (after you fulfill it).

You will also have to notify the Store that the request is fulfilled - by calling [ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.reportconsumablefulfillmentasync.aspx).

You can also take a look at [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.reportconsumablefulfillmentasync.aspx).

Comment: ah, thanks. And if I need non-consumable product (as in iOS) than I need to set durable to product type, right?

Comment: @BoJIHanpocmombI Yes, durable product can last forever or specified time. I see that [Zhaph - Ben Duguid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27566937/2681948) provided nice explanation.

Comment: One more question, what will happen if I will call ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync with durable product? I didn't find any way to detect consumable or durable product type. So I'm processing both in one method.

Comment: @BoJIHanpocmombI I'm not sure, check MSDN and this what will be returned in CurrentAppSimulator. Durable/Consumable type is defined in Store or inside your proxy file.

Answer (score 1):

**Durable** items are designed to be purchased only once (unless you're running on Windows Phone 8.1+ in which case you can set the **Product Lifetime** to a value other than "Forever" which will force the user to purchase it again to keep using it).

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206721%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> **Durable** A product that’s bought and owned by the buyer forever, like a game level. Durable products aren’t consumed.

And from [VS Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/in-app-purchasing-for-windows-phone-8.aspx) (*emphasis added*):

> BuySuperWeapon will demonstrate an example of a durable (*an item that can be purchased only once*). [...] once a user has purchased it, he can use it as long as he plays the game

If you want to allow a user to purchase multiple of the same thing (even if "in game" they will be available forever - for example an upgrade slot or something), you need to use the **Consumable** product type.

Note that in the simulator, the phone is torn down and reset each time you stop it, so in real use the user will not be able purchase more of your durable items even in different game sessions.